# pointers and values

Tags: c, pointers

I have written the following code, and it prints the root value correctly, but not the ret value. Here a memory address is potentially printed (1707388). I believe that ret could now be modified and the result would be seen in main. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
int value;
    int order;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

typedef struct node node_t;

node_t array[10];

void createTree(node_t *p, int order){
    p->value = rand()%10;
    p->order = order;
    printf("%i", p->value);
    printf(" ");
    printf("%i\n", p->order);
    if (!order){
        p->left = NULL;
        p->right = NULL;
        return; 
    }
    order--;
    createTree(&p->left, order);
    createTree(&p->right, order);
}

void traverse(node_t *current, node_t *ret, int size){
    printf("%i\n", current->value); 
    if (current->value > size){
        ret = current;
        traverse(&current->left, &ret, size);
        traverse(&current->right, &ret, size); 
    } 
    return;
}

int main(void){
    node_t *root = &array[0];
    node_t *ret;
    srand(time(NULL));
    createTree(root, 4);
    int i = 3;
    printf("%s", "root-value: ");
    printf("%i\n", root->value);
    traverse(root, ret, i);
    printf("%s", "root-value: ");
    printf("%i\n", root->value);
    printf("%i\n", ret->value);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You need to learn not only how to write code, but also how to debug it.

Comment: Andrey. Obviously you are right, but why state it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `ret` by value to

```
void traverse(node_t *current, node_t *ret, int size){
```

When the function changes `ret`, the changes do not propagate back to the caller.

This means that `ret` in `main()` remains uninitialized, and the behaviour of your code is undefined.

To fix this, make `traverse` either return `ret`, or take it as `node_t**`.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
void createTree(node_t *p, int order)
```

Should be

```
void createTree(node_t **p, int order)
```

Otherwise you are modifying a *local* `node_t` pointer, instead of the one outside the function. Your tree isn't being built properly either.

Comment: And assign to `*ret` in the function.

Answer (score 2):

There are few issues with the code.

First, you don't correctly allocate the memory for nodes. In your code, you are passing wrong pointer type, futhermore, pointer to uninitialized area.

Here, how it can be used differently:

```
 node_t *createTree(int order)
 {
     node_t *result = malloc(sizeof(*result));
     result->value = rand() % 10;
     result->order = order;
     if (order)
     {
         result->left = createTree(order - 1);
         result->right = createTree(order - 1);
     }
     else
     {
         result->left = result->right = 0;
     }
     return result;
 }
```

Then, your traverse function need some block to restrict agains failed search:

```
node_t *traverse(node_t *current, int size)
{
    node_t *ret = NULL;

    if (current->value > size)
    {
        // assuming current node fit - stops the search
        ret = current;
    } 

    if (!ret && current->left)
    {
        // try left node
        ret = traverse(current->left, size);
    }
    if (!ret && current->right)
    {
        // try right node
        ret = traverse(current->right, size); 
    }
    return ret;
}
```

In case you need (usually you do), here is a `destroyTree`:

```
void destroyTree(node_t *node)
{
    if (!node) return; // we treat NULL as a valid pointer for simplicity

    destroyTree(node->left);
    destroyTree(node->right);
    free(node);
}
```

And here is a usage example:

```
node_t *root, *found;

root = createTree(4);
found = traverse(root, 3);
if (found)
{
   printf("Found!");
}
destroyTree(root);
```

Comment: thank you valeri:) I believe I dont need to use malloc since I statically set aside memory for my array in the top, and assign the address of the first index to my pointer.

Comment: @dexter without malloc or its equivalent your code would not work :) tree-like structures require some kind of memory management. Allocating static array is not suffient.

Comment: valerie. Why is that? I mean, enough memory should be available there in the array (as long as I dont go outside the array).

Comment: @dexter you misspeled my name:) the reason is that your data structure in a way recursive. And you simply cant describe it with a flat data type. So every node needs some memory allocation, which can be based either on `malloc/free` or custom memory allocation. In your initial code `left/right` contains garbage as they are uninitialized pointers.

Answer (score 1):

In `traverse(node_t *current, node_t *ret, int size)`, `ret` is a stack variable. In other words, you are passing the pointer **by value**, instead of passing it **by reference**.

What have you done at the moment is essentially the same as:

```
int f(int i) {
   ...
   i = <any value>;
   ...
}
```

In this case you are modifying only a copy of the value.

In your program, you are also modifying a copy of the pointer. Outside of the function the pointer stays not modified.

If you want to modify it, you need to pass a pointer to it:

```
void traverse(node_t *current, node_t **ret, int size){
    ...
    *ret = current;
    ...
    return;
}
```

The same for `createTree()`.